# How do I fix glUseProgram error in Android

Tags: android, mobile, opengl-es, textures

While learning how OpenGL ES works, I'm trying to get a textured square to appear on my screen. Here is the relevant code to the square. The code is based on the google example:

```
public class Shape2Square {

private static final String TAG = "Shape2Square";
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;"+
        "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;"+
        "void main() {" +
        "v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;"+
        "gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
        "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform sampler2D u_Texture"+
        "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;"+
        "void main() {" +
        "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);"+
        "}";
    private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private final int mProgram;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
    private int mtexture;
    private int mtexCoordHandler;
    private int mtextureHandler;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static float squareCoords[] = { -0.3f,  -0.3f, 0.0f,   // top left
                                    -0.3f, 0.3f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
                                     0.3f, 0.3f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
                                     0.3f,  -0.3f, 0.0f }; // top right
    // u,v 
    static float texturedata[] =   {0.0f, 0.0f,
                           0.0f, 1.0f,
                           1.0f, 1.0f,
                           1.0f, 0.0f};


    private final short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;

    public Shape2Square() {
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer bbtexture = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texturedata.length*4);
        bbtexture.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = bbtexture.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texturedata);
        textureBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = CommonMethods.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                                                   vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = CommonMethods.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                                                     fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();       
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glCreateProgram");     
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader); 
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glAttachShader"); 
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glAttachShader"); 
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glLinkProgram");                 
    }
```

The trouble I get from logcat points to the "draw" method of this square. Note the `CommonMethods.loadTexture` simply loads a bitmap code into OPEN GL:

**EDIT1: (added checkGlErrors all over the code)**

```
    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix, int textureid) {
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glUseProgram");



        vertexBuffer.position(0);
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");


        textureBuffer.position(0);  
        mtexCoordHandler = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,"a_TexCoordinate");
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mtexCoordHandler);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mtexCoordHandler, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 8, textureBuffer);            
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");


        mtextureHandler = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_Texture");
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("mtextureHandler");
        mtexture = CommonMethods.loadTexture(textureid);

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glActiveTexture");
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mtexture);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glBindTexture");
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mtextureHandler, 0);      
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glUniform1i");

        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
                              GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glDrawElements");

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        Shape2Square.checkGlError("glDisableVertexAttribArray");



    }
    public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e(TAG, glOperation + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }
```

Doing this causes an error and forces the application to shut down. logcat leads to `glGetUniformLocation` with the most likely culprit of `mMVPMatrixHandle` after messing about with the code, which is strange, because it worked before. To prove my point, if I delete all the Texture code and add a vColor instead (both in the actual code and the fragmentShadercode) with all the usual relevance, then I will get the coloured square. I don't understand how the mistake lies with `glGetUniformLocation` or how to fix it so any help is appreciated.

EDIT1: So I tried to blank out the checkglerror of the "glgetuniformlocation" but this comes to a disappointment as now the error comes in the form of "glUniformMatrix4fv". Something is terribly wrong...

EDIT2: decided to use checkglerror all over the code, and so far it seems that the ENTIRE draw method (including the glUseProgram) has an error. The gl bits which occur before the draw method (which includes attaching shader and linking) are ok with no errors.

Comment: Be sure that your shaders are compiled by the same thread that calls glUseProgram() and glDrawArrays().  Also, you need to check for gl errors more often.

Comment: I'm unsure by what you mean. glUseProgram() and glDrawElements() (if that is what you meant, not glDrawArrays()) are within the same draw method. In short, the draw method grabs the mProgram, attaches the position coordinate, the texture coordinate, binds the texture and then draws the lot (at least that is what i think it is doing). Surely all those methods would be compiled in the same thread anyway? Im not sure how a new thread could be called here? Also, I will update the code with checkglerrors all over.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what i did wrong (im a noob...).
The fragmentShadercode after u_Texture should have ";" behind it. Can't believe that held me back 2 days :(. Anyways thanks for the help ClayMontgomery. I have drawn the shape upside down though, but i'm pretty sure I can fix that.